# How to recognize a Runner's Knee?

Tags: exercise, running, knees

I started my exercise routine back up in June and recently started getting into walking/running around my neighborhood on my off days from lifting weights.  Last week I pushed myself a little harder and now I have some slight pain that seems to be just below my kneecap.  Periodically as I'm going down my stairs at home my leg feels like it might go out but doesn't.  Everything that I've read says to limit strain on the effected leg and try to avoid stairs (which is not possible at all at work and/or home).

If this is runner's knee how long should this last and is there anything else that I can do to help with the healing process?  My exercise routine has barbell squats 3X week and some of the  other exercises also require me to be standing/kneeling/slight squat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be runner's knee (chondromalacia) or a bit of tendonitis.  Rest and Naproxen (Aleve) will do the trick.

Always ease into running longer or faster.  Don't increase mileage or effort by more than 10% per week.

I should also add that physical therapy is usually a common treatment.  Runner's knee can be caused, besides overuse, by weak stabilizing muscles of the hips, knees and ankles.  You may wish to see a doctor (sports medicine or physical therapist) to get a proper diagnosis and for therapy exercises.

Comment: would you care to add a more formal description of how to recognize a Runner's Knee? Just to make your answer more complete.